# Fisher test returns 1

Tags: r

I have a dataframe names `hesc_fisher` for patent grants in the EU and the US and want to check the disparity of grants in the EU and US with a fisher test. The `dput` of my data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015
), EU = c(3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
0), US = c(3, 4, 37, 6, 13, 26, 8, 18, 38, 10, 21, 37, 21, 31, 
19, 17, 12, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I used the fisher test by:

```
fisher.test(hesc_fisher$US, hesc_fisher$EU)
```

My output is:

```
Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  hesc_fisher$US and hesc_fisher$EU
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

which is kind of weird to me because I expected the data from the EU and US to be significantly different from each other. Therefore I want to ask: did I understand the fisher test wrong or did I err in my coding? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By checking the `?fisher.test`

> x  -
>   either a two-dimensional contingency table in matrix form, or a factor object.
>
> y 
>   a factor object; ignored if x is a matrix.

We can reshape the datasset into a 'long' dataframe and specify the 'y' column as the 'key' column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(df1, key, val, EU:US) %>%
       {fisher.test(.$val, .$key)$p.value}
#[1] 0.0007857974
```